# Вывести определенный кусок текста

Tags: python-3.x, текст

```
except Exception:
    exception = traceback.format_exc()
    self.exceptions.append(exception)
    await self.bot.api.messages.send(message=exception, user_id=385914179)
```

Как вывести только кусок текста который на картинке?

[image: Изображение]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**как то так**

```
import traceback
from threading import Thread

def run():
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            print(t)
    except Exception:
       exception = traceback.format_exc()[34:]
       print(exception)
th = Thread(target=run)
th.start()
```